# SQL query minimum maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I need to get maximum and  minimum values but also I need to get row id of these maximum or minimum on the same row.

```
SELECT MIN([Value]), MAX([Value]), id 
FROM [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues] 
GROUP BY indicatorid
```

Comment: Do you require the ID and MIN, and then the ID and Max. In 2 rows? next to each other?

Comment: yes it would be cool if ID and MIN, and then the ID and Max ar next to each other

Comment: @Woland: Would you mind to edit your question to reflect the changed requirement?

Comment: Wouldn't it also make more sense if you returned the 'indicatorid' as a column so that you can see which indicatorid each min and max are for?

Comment: @Woland: It seems to me that you don't fully understand yourself what it is that you want. I have submitted an answer together with some test data. If this doesn't meet your requirements, could you please adapt the test data and/or expected results and include it in an update to your question so that we all can see unambiguously what result set you want.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Waht if there are many rows with min or max value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very unclear what you want from your question. Do you really want the GROUP BY indicatorid? If not then it's quite simple and you already have many answers. But if you do want to GROUP BY then it's more difficult and no-one has got it quite right yet. I also assume that you only want one row per indicatorid, and if there are duplicate rows that have the same max/min then it's better to just choose one of them arbitrarily instead of returning both.

Here's my attempt, using CTEs (requires SQL Server 2005 or newer):

```
WITH
    RowNumbers AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY indicatorid, value) AS RowNumber, *
        FROM [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues]),
    MinRowNumbers AS (
        SELECT indicatorid, MIN(RowNumber) AS RowNumber FROM RowNumbers GROUP BY indicatorid),
    MaxRowNumbers AS (
        SELECT indicatorid, MAX(RowNumber) AS RowNumber FROM RowNumbers GROUP BY indicatorid)
SELECT
    MinRowNumbers.indicatorid,
    RN1.Value AS MinValue,
    RN1.ID AS MinValueId,
    RN2.Value AS MaxValue,
    RN2.ID AS MaxValueId
FROM MinRowNumbers
JOIN MaxRowNumbers ON MinRowNumbers.indicatorid = MaxRowNumbers.indicatorid
JOIN RowNumbers RN1 ON MinRowNumbers.RowNumber = RN1.RowNumber
JOIN RowNumbers RN2 ON MaxRowNumbers.RowNumber = RN2.RowNumber
```

Here is some data I used to test it:

```
CREATE TABLE AnalystEstimateValues (ID int, indicatorid int, Value int);

INSERT INTO AnalystEstimateValues (ID, indicatorid , Value) VALUES
(1, 1, 4),
(2, 1, 4),
(3, 2, 6),
(4, 1, 2),
(5, 2, 2),
(6, 2, 5),
(7, 3, 0);
```

And here's the output I get:

```
indicatorid MinValue MinValueId MaxValue MaxValueId
          1        2          4        4          2
          2        2          5        6          3
          3        0          7        0          7
```

If this isn't what you want, can you please try to improve your question to tell us what you do want?

---

Update: Here's an alternative solution based on Craig Young's answer but using joins instead of subselects:

```
WITH
    UniqueIds AS (
        SELECT IndicatorId, Value, MIN(id) AS Id
        FROM AnalystEstimateValues
        GROUP BY IndicatorId, Value)
SELECT
    lims.IndicatorId,
    MinValue,
    T1.Id AS MinValueId,
    MaxValue,
    T2.Id AS MaxValueId 
FROM (
        SELECT
            IndicatorId,
            MIN(Value) as MinValue,
            MAX(Value) as MaxValue
        FROM AnalystEstimateValues
        GROUP BY IndicatorId) lims
JOIN UniqueIds T1 ON lims.IndicatorId = T1.IndicatorId AND lims.MinValue = T1.Value
JOIN UniqueIds T2 ON lims.IndicatorId = T2.IndicatorId AND lims.MaxValue = T2.Value
```

This is cleaner and probably also faster than my first version, although I haven't run performance tests to verify this.

Comment: OK, I was lucky. :) I think next time you should spend a little more time on your question so that the responses better match what you want. In fact I don't think this is the best way to solve this problem - it could be too slow. I see that you already accepted it, but I hope that you have confirmed that it is fast enough for your data before doing so. If someone can later solve this in a better way now that they can see what you want, then you should accept their answer instead of this one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you've used; I must read up on it. As a performance note, you have 2 GROUP BY sub-queries - one for MIN and the other for MAX. You should be able to combine these into a single sub-query and derive a significant performance improvement.

Comment: Yep that should be possible, and will also save a join at the end. I was hoping someone could find a way to do this without using rownumbers, because I think this will require a full table scan even though only the min and max are needed.

Comment: You can check out my solution which doesn't use row numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979046/sql-query-minimum-maximum/1979852#1979852  It uses 3 sub-queries in total, each having potential to benefit from the same (IndicatorId, Value) index depending on column stats.

Answer (score 1):

If Min = Max, you'll the get same IDs (there may be tied Min and Max values)

If not, there is/are ID(s) *per* min/max value.

You can have 2 rows or 4 columns, basically.

```
SELECT
    Mn.ID, foo.MinVal,
    Mx.ID, foo.MaxVal     
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MIN([Value]) AS MinVal,
        MAX([Value]) AS MaxVal,
        indicatorid
    FROM
        [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues] 
    GROUP BY
        indicatorid
    ) foo
    JOIN
    [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues] Mn ON
            foo.MinVal = Mn.[Value] AND foo.indicatorid = Mn.indicatorid
    JOIN
    [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues] Mx ON
            foo.MaxVal = Mx.[Value] AND foo.indicatorid = Mx.indicatorid
```

Edit:

The TOP solutions won't give you rows where you have tied MIN/MAX values unless defined WITH TIES

Comment: ON foo.MinVal = Mn.[Value] and ON foo.MaxVal = Mx.[Value]

is not possible because there might be duplicate values

Comment: So: which ID do you want if there are duplicates? How would you decide one ID over another?

Comment: If you want to allow returning multiple result like this, you should include the indicatorid in the join otherwise you could fetch rows from the wrong group. I.e. you need this: `ON foo.MinVal = Mn.[Value] AND foo.indicatorid = Mn.indicatorid`.

Answer (score 1):

**Important question**
Mark Byers' sample data shows a scenario that you need to contemplate:

- IndicatorId=1 has a max value of 4.
- There are two Id's that share the same max value (1 & 2).

So which of the two id's should be displayed?

I have assumed it sufficient to display the lowest id. The following query should be the most efficient, and would benefit from an index on (indicatorid, Value).

```
SELECT  lims.*,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(id)
        FROM    AnalystEstimateValues m
        WHERE   m.IndicatorId = lims.IndicatorId
            AND m.Value = lims.MinValue
        ) AS MinId,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(id)
        FROM    AnalystEstimateValues m
        WHERE   m.IndicatorId = lims.IndicatorId
            AND m.Value = lims.MaxValue
        ) AS MaxId
FROM    (
        SELECT  IndicatorId,
                MIN(Value) as MinValue,
                MAX(Value) as MaxValue
        FROM    AnalystEstimateValues
        GROUP BY IndicatorId
        ) lims
```

Comment: This produces the correct result according to my example test data. It uses a correlated subselect so I'm not sure it will always be fast - if there are a very large number of very small indicatorid groups I suspect it will be slower. But it's very hard to guess these things without trying it on more realistic data. I still feel that there must be a better way to do this but +1 anyway.

Comment: I have made a modified version of your solution and appended it to the end of my first answer. I basically do the same thing but using JOINs instead of correlated subselects. I *guess* this will be faster but it would require proper testing to find out for sure. I don't plan to do that - it's too much effort to create realistic test data - but if someone else does this (Woland?), I'd be very interested to know the results.

Comment: PS: I'd guess that your solution is fine as there probably aren't all that many indicatorids.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would return the max/min for each ID as you are grouping by the ID. Try something like this

```
SELECT tblFoo.ID, tblFoo.Value
FROM tblFoo
WHERE (((tblFoo.Value)=(SELECT MAX( [tblFoo]![Value] ) FROM tblFoo))) 
   OR (((tblFoo.Value)=(SELECT MIN( [tblFoo]![Value] ) FROM tblFoo)));
```

Comment: You too has lost the grouping construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID, 
    'min' as type, 
    value 
FROM 
    AnalystEstimateValues 
WHERE 
   value = (select min(value) from AnalystEstimateValues)
UNION
   SELECT TOP 1
    ID, 
    'max' as type, 
    value 
FROM 
    AnalystEstimateValues 
WHERE 
   value = (select max(value ) from AnalystEstimateValues)
```

Comment: You too has lost the grouping construct.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it, though I don't have mssql so I can't test it. Especially the square brackets may need tweaking. Other than that it should be fairly standard sql and does what you want.

It gets all min (id/value) and max (id/value) grouped by indicatorid. **In the same row.**

```
SELECT mint.indicatorid, mint.min_id, mint.min_value, maxt.max_id, maxt.max_value
FROM (
    SELECT indicatorid, id as min_id, MIN([Value]) AS min_value
    FROM [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues]
    HAVING [Value] = min_value
    GROUP BY indicatorid
) mint JOIN (
    SELECT indicatorid, id as max_id, MAX([Value]) AS max_value
    FROM [AnalystEstimates].[dbo].[AnalystEstimateValues]
    HAVING [Value] = max_value
    GROUP BY indicatorid
) maxt ON mint.indicatorid = maxt.indicatorid
```

Comment: I got this error "ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."